# Can't import groovy classes into test

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

I have been playing around with a Gradle / Groovy project and have created some classes under `src/main/groovy/com/test/demo`. I was going to then add some unit tests under `src/test/groovy/com/test/demo`, however I cannot seem to get the classes in `src/main` to be recognized (import). I am using IntelliJ 2016.3.3.  I am sure this is user error (new to Gradle / Groovy).

Is it my `build.gradle` config?

```
group 'com.test.demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'demo',
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question does not have typos, then your file structure is probably wrong. It should be `src/main/groovy/com/test/demo`, not `src/main/groovy/com.test.demo`.

Btw. since 2014-12-04 JUnit 4.12 is released.

Comment: I will edit my question, the directory structure is as you have stated.

Comment: Then please post your Gradle output, your file structure and maybe your classes contents.

Answer (score 2):

I found this page because I was having similar issues. I started off with my plugin in a .gradle file and had moved it into its own groovy project, and that's when I started seeing this issue.

It turned out that I had forgotten to add a package declaration at the top of my plugin's .groovy file when I moved it to its own project, under src/main/groovy/...